# How to exit from a for each loop if the inner if condition satisfies, if its a javascript which is asynchronous in nature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I want to exit from the for each loop, the moment the text includes ImageResizingOrg. I could have easily done this if its a synchronous. As javascript is asynchronous, I need to solve this. Any solutions

```
organizationLocator.each(function(element) {

            FunctionLibrary.getText(element, organizationName).then(function(text) {
                logger.info(text);
                if (text.includes('ImageResizingOrg')) {

                    FunctionLibrary.click(element, organizationName);



                }
            })

        })
```

Comment: have you tried a break;

Comment: break won't work here, as its not a regular loop but an anonymous callback function that gets called by each() for every instance. However, `return false;` should do the trick!

Comment: If `FunctionLibrary.getText` is ASYNC then you will already be at the end of each

Comment: @Connum No it doesn't work

Comment: Yes @DanielKrom its async

Comment: @hello_abhishek well, I suggest you to read about how async javascript works, basically the first `.then` callback will only be called at least after all `.each`, I suggest you to read maybe about `Promise.race` that can resolve the first promise the returns or use Promise chaining

Comment: yes that will the ultimate saviour :D

Answer (score 1):

To solve your loop problem, use the [filter](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function. Assuming your `organizationLocator` is an array of elements, you can do this:

```
organizationLocator.filter(function (elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text.indexOf('ImageResizingOrg') > -1;
    });
}).first().click();
```

Answer (score -2):

You could make your loop "synchronous" by passing each element in the "then" method.

By doing so, you can stop the loop whenever you want.

```
var inc = 0,
    doLoop = function (element) {

        FunctionLibrary.getText(element, organizationName).then(function (text) {
            logger.info(text);

            inc += 1;

            if (text.includes('ImageResizingOrg')) {
                FunctionLibrary.click(element, organizationName);
            } else if (inc < organizationLocator.length) {
                doLoop(organizationLocator[inc]);

            }
        });

    };

doLoop(organizationLocator[inc]);
```